# Is it possible fetch package details from Nuget private store using REST API?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, nuget, npm-check-updates

I am trying to build an Angular 8 application which for showing the Nuget package details from a custom store. Is it possible fetch package details from NPM custom store using REST API.?

Similar to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/api/query-for-all-published-packages

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-api
This is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: am looking for something similar to this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/api/query-for-all-published-packages